# Retain the search value in Autocomplete textbox even after search

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, material-ui, autocomplete

I want to prevent the search text from disappearing after selecting an item from the filtered options in the Autocomplete component in mui autocomplete checkbox.

Tried setting the state variable for input as well.But it does not work. here is code sandbox link.enter image description here

https://codesandbox.io/s/zx49gs?file=/Demo.tsx:572-583

[search text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzdmJ.png)
[click on any option from search options, search text disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqRWQ.png)